# Pixi.js best way to create a dragable and clickable handle that rotates around a point

Tags: javascript, game-physics, pixi.js

[image][image][image]

I have 8 handle graphics that represent 5 different states (closed, flow rate 1, flow rate 2, flow rate 3, flow rate 4). Handle graphics 6,7, and 8 also represent flow rate 1, 2, and 3. The images depict a buret handle that rotates around a center point. For each handle state, I need to show the matching texture. I need the user to be able to drag the handle and have it move through the different graphics as the mouse moves around the center point. I also need the user to be able to click on the right side to increase the flow rate and click on the left side to decrease the flow rate.

I have looking into using getBounds() from the image and using that as a hit box but that seems like it won't work because i am removing the old texture and adding a new one depending on the mouse position when dragging. not to mention the images all have similar dimensions.

I have also though about creating 16 hit boxes (2 for each of the 8 images, 1 on the left side for decreasing flow rate, one on the right side for increasing flow rate) and adding and removing the hit boxes with the texture but this seems overly tedious and i don't think it will work with dragging.

Let me know if you have any ideas!

Thanks

Comment: the "handle" (red thing) and "buret" are separate sprites?

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Drag a rotating switch

Assuming you get a mouse coord that is relative to the valve eg mouse event `pageX`, `pageY` properties.

You can create a function that takes the element, number valve steps, and mouse coords and spits out the values you want.

```
function getValueSetting(x, y, valveSteps, valveElement) {
    const bounds = valveElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    const centerX = (bounds.left + bounds.right) / 2;
    const centerY = (bounds.top + bounds.bottom) / 2;
    const left = x < centerX;
    const distance = Math.hypot(x - centerX, y - centerY);
    const pos = (Math.atan2(y - centerY, x - centerX) + Math.PI) / (Math.PI * 2);
    return {
        left,
        right: !left,
        distance,
        pos: Math.round(pos * valveSteps - (valveSteps / 4)),   
    };
}
```

If the valve positions step by 1 hour on the clock make  `valveSteps = 12`

Call the function `const valveState = getValueSetting(mouseEvent.pageX, mouseEvent.pageY, 12, valveElment);`

The object returned will have bools for `left` and `right` of the center, and `pos` will be one of 12 positions starting at 12 o'clock `pos = 0` to 11 o'clock `pos === 11`. The `distance` property is the distance from the valve.

In the function the angle position subtracts  `(valveSteps / 4)` because `Math.atan2` return 0 at the 3 o'clock mark. The subtract  `(valveSteps / 4)` rotate back 1 quarter turn to set 0 at 12 o'clock.

### Example

The example draws 5 valve positions.

Move the mouse over the valve handle (red) and the cursor will change to a pointer. Click and drag the mouse to turn the valve. Once dragging the mouse will hold the valve until you release the button.

If not over the handle, but near the valve clicks left and right will message appropriate message.

```js
const size = 64;  // size of image
const valveSteps = 12; // total number of angle steps
const valveStep = (Math.PI * 2) / valveSteps; // angle steps in radians
const startAngle = -valveStep * 2; // visual start angle of handle
const valveStart = 1; // starting pos of valve

setTimeout(() => {
    const valves = [
       createValve(64, startAngle),
       createValve(64, startAngle + valveStep),
       createValve(64, startAngle + valveStep * 2),
       createValve(64, startAngle + valveStep * 3),
       createValve(64, startAngle + valveStep * 4),
    ];

    setValve(valves[0]);
    var dragging = false;
    var currentPos = 0;
    var level = 0;
    mouse.onupdate = () => {
        const valveSetting = getValueSetting(mouse.x, mouse.y, valveSteps, valveA);
        if (valveSetting.distance < size && valveSetting.pos - valveStart === currentPos) {
            document.body.style.cursor = "pointer";
        } else {
            document.body.style.cursor = "default";
        }

        if (mouse.button && (valveSetting.distance < size || dragging)) {
            if (valveSetting.distance < size / 2 && valveSetting.pos - valveStart === currentPos) {
                if (valveSetting.pos >= valveStart && valveSetting.pos < valveStart + valves.length) {
                    dragging = true;
                }
            }
            console.clear()
            if (dragging) {
                let pos = valveSetting.pos - valveStart;
                pos = pos < 0 ? 0 : pos > valves.length - 1 ? valves.length - 1 : pos
                setValve(valves[pos]);
                currentPos = pos;
                console.log("Valve pos: " + pos);                
            } else if (valveSetting.left) {
                level --;
                console.log("Turn down " + level);
                mouse.button = false;
            } else if (valveSetting.right) {
                level ++;
                console.log("Turn up " + level);
                mouse.button = false;
            }
        } else {
            dragging = false;
        }
    }

},0);

function setValve(image) {
    valveA.innerHTML = "";
    $$(valveA, image);  // appends image to element valveA
}
function getValueSetting(x, y, valveSteps, valveElement) {
    const bounds = valveElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    const centerX = (bounds.left + bounds.right) / 2;
    const centerY = (bounds.top + bounds.bottom) / 2;
    const left = x < centerX;
    const distance = Math.hypot(x - centerX, y - centerY);
    const pos = (Math.atan2(y - centerY, x - centerX) + Math.PI) / (Math.PI * 2);
    return {
        left,
        right: !left,
        distance,
        pos: Math.round(pos * valveSteps - (valveSteps / 4)), 
    };
}

function createValve(size, angle) {
    const canvas = $("canvas", {width: size, height: size});
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    const r = size * 0.4;
    const c = size / 2;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.lineWidth = 8;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineTo(Math.cos(angle) * r + c, Math.sin(angle) * r + c);
    ctx.lineTo(-Math.cos(angle) * r * 0.2 + c, -Math.sin(angle) * r * 0.2 + c);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(c, c, 8, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.stroke();


    return canvas;
}


// Boiler plate
const $ = (tag, props = {}) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), props);
const $$ = (p, ...sibs) => sibs.reduce((p,sib) => (p.appendChild(sib), p), p);
const mouse  = {x : 0, y : 0, button : false}
function mouseEvents(e){
      mouse.x = e.pageX;
      mouse.y = e.pageY;
      mouse.button = e.type === "mousedown" ? true : e.type === "mouseup" ? false : mouse.button;
    mouse.onupdate && mouse.onupdate();
}
["down","up","move"].forEach(name => document.addEventListener("mouse" + name,mouseEvents));
```

```css
.valveContainer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left 30px;
    border: 2px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div id="valveA" class="valveContainer"></div>
```

Comment: This was not the way I solved it, but It definitely works and pointed me in the right direction. Thank you for your time!